# Is there a function for knowing which percentage of my geometry is included in one other?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

I need to know if a geometry is approximately contained in one other. Sometimes, the geomtries I have where badly designed and a very small part of it is outside of the one they are supposed to be in.

ST_Contains cannot return true with these bad geomtries

I'd like to find a POSTGIS function returning the geomtry A contains X% of the geometry B. Example: `ST_containing_rate(geometry A, geometry B)` returning a percentage

Or a function which will return true if the geometry A contains X% of the geometry B. Example: `ST_contains_at_least(geometry A, geomtry B, percentage p)` returning true or false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way of doing it would be:

```
ST_Area(ST_Intersection(geometry A, geometry B)) / ST_Area(geom B) > percentage
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a good feature that should be added to PostGIS. However, you can get around this by using the clip function (ST_Intersection(geometry A, geometry B)) and then comparing the returned geometry with the original geometry A.

Comment: How should I compare it if the geometry B is much more smaller than the geomtry A ?
Can I get a percentage ?